# Which dbfs uses "databricks cli" with profile in .databrickscfg pointing to host with databricks community edition workspace url?

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition, databricks-cli

I have installed "databricks cli" on a Windows machine and I have configured the .databrickscfg configuration file pointing the host to the url of the workspace that appears when I access my databricks community edition account via the web.

However, when I execute commands in a command window of type "databricks fs ls dbfs:/" the information I get is not the same as what I see via the web in the "data -> dbfs" option. It seems that a different dbfs is being accessed.

What should I do so that the commands I execute from "databricks fs..." use the same dbfs that I access via the web in my Databricks Community Edition account?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to check the path - Go to data -> <Folder you are looking for> -> In the dropdown select Copy Path - check the value that is coming - my guess is that dbfs folder inside data would be dbfs:/dbfs/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have indicated the 2 path options but:

databricks fs ls dbfs:/FileStore/my_test_data/name_file.txt
Error: b'{"error_code":"RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"No file or directory exists on path dbfs:/FileStore/my_test_data/name_file.txt."}'

databricks fs ls dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/my_test_data/name_file.txt
Error: b'{"error_code":"RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"No file or directory exists on path dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/my_test_data/name_file.txt."}'

Comment: just curious - how did you get a PAT token for community edition - for me it seems to be hidden...

Comment: Hi again, in Community Edition, as I understood it, there is no Authentication Token, the Profile of the generated file ".databrickscfg" was using User and Password. Step content:

[DEFAULT]
host=https://community.cloud.databricks.com/?o=<my_workspace_id>
username = <my_user_account>
password = <my_password>
jobs-api-version = 2.0

Comment: How about it - you are right - They indeed show something different or rather my guess is that only folders with proper access show up here...maybe the mount isn't happening in a way we are expecting...maybe someone more knowledgeable can help...Sorry...